# Recover/undo discarded changes in git/magit on unstaged files

Tags: magit, git

I accidentally pressed "k" (a magit command) and discarded some unstaged changes.  Is there a way to undo this?  Or did I discover one of the few ways to actually lose work while using git?

Comment: Have you tried using `undo` in the affected buffers? (Assuming you had them open.)

Comment: Note that if the changes were never staged then you weren't "using git" so to speak -- git never knew about those changes.

Comment: @phils great suggestion.  I didn't think of this during my panic, unfortunately.

Comment: @phils git knew about them, but only in a general sense, i.e. git knew there were unstaged changes to files it was tracking.  And it was a git command that discarded those changes.  But your point is well taken.

Comment: Right, although it's more that git will *figure out on demand* if there are unstaged changes (and then, I believe, immediately forget again).  Unless it's told to store the changeset in some way, it won't remember it.

Comment: It's an interesting notion, though, that git could be told to remember these kinds of discarded changes... In principle I don't see why Magit couldn't be configured to create a new unreachable commit when deleting changes, and log the hash.  In time, garbage collection would clean them up, but in the case of an accident you could check the log and re-apply that commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mention in the comments, if, at the time you discard a change, a buffer is visiting the file that is modified by the discard, then you can simply go to that buffer and undo the change.

The comments also mention that Magit could create a commit whenever it performs an action that destroys data that could otherwise not be recovered. Turns out Magit has been doing that for years, but only if told to do so.

This is implemented using several minor-modes that can be enabled individually. To enable them all use this.

```
(use-package magit-wip
  :after magit
  :config
  (magit-wip-before-change-mode)
  (magit-wip-after-apply-mode)
  (magit-wip-after-save-mode))
```

You should also add this line at the top-level (not inside `use-package`):

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'magit-wip-commit-initial-backup)
```

Some other related settings:

```
(use-package magit
  :config
  (setq magit-wip-merge-branch t)
  (magit-define-popup-action 'magit-log-popup
    ?i "Index wipref" 'magit-wip-log-index)
  (magit-define-popup-action 'magit-log-popup
    ?w "Worktree wipref" 'magit-wip-log-worktree))
```

Most of this is documented [in the manual](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Wip-Modes.html). Also see the doc-string of `magit-wip-merge-branch`.

Comment: Since `magit` now uses `transient` rather than `magit-popup`, the last "other settings" bit doesn't work directly, but throws a warning. Here's alternative code to fix it:

```
(use-package magit
  :config
  (setq magit-wip-merge-branch t)
  (transient-append-suffix 'magit-log "a"
    '("i" "Index wipref" magit-wip-log-index))
  (transient-append-suffix 'magit-log "i"
    '("w" "Worktree wipref" magit-wip-log-worktree)))
```

Comment: `"i"` and `"w"` are now automatically added to magit-log when `magit-wip-mode` is turned on. And it is discouraged to used the individual modes. So just `(magit-wip-mode 1)` should do.